# Change Bootstrap 3 Global Font Size at Breakpoint

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 and would like to change the font-size across the site at each breakpoint, so that I can change the font size in one place and have it cascade to all the Bootstrap components.

The base font sizes I would like are:

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) { // Base font size is 12px }
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) { // Base font size is 13px }
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) and (max-width: @screen-md-max) { // Base font size is 14px }
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { // Base font size is 16px }
```

However, I can see no way of doing this. It seems that all the font-size values are hard-coded. Is the only way for me to do this to manually redefine each component's font size at each breakpoint?

To clarify, I'm looking for a way to specify a different base font size at each breakpoint so that all components use the new base font size.

Otherwise what is the option? That at each breakpoint I have to change fontSize of every header, `p`, `cite` by hand?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change base font size with a media query and define all your site's font sizes using "em"s instead of "px".

Proceed as such:

1) Define global font size based on breakpoints (code below is written in less)

```
body {
  @media (max-width: @screen-xs-min) {
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  @media (min-width: @screen-xs-min) and (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
    font-size: 11px;
  }

  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

2) Define elements' font sizes based on their parents'. For instance:

```
body div {
    font-size: 1em; // same size as parent

    p {
        font-size: 0.8em; // a little bit smaller
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Its better to use Font-size for header as 24px; and for content as 14px; so that its perfect Fit for all the devices, and readability purpose. If you want to reduce the font size at each break point. Then u have to make use of media queries. or give font in percentage.